# piping head and tail with globbing

Tags: command-line, wildcards, tail, head

I have several files in the same dir for which I want to print certain lines from a continuous interval, e.g., from 15th to 20th.

For a single file, this works `head -n20 file.txt | tail -n6`,
but **how I can make it work for the globbing patterns**, e.g., for all txt files in this dir `*.txt`?

`head -n20 *.txt | tail -n6 # this only crops results of head -n20`

**EDIT1**: I am also aware of the workaround with `for`, but instead I am hoping to learn how to define piping of several operations in a uniform way that also works with wildcards.

p.s. probably having the standard headers, like `==> file.txt <==` which `head` and `tail` give when combined with wildcards, is too much to ask.

p.p.s. using ubuntu, but a unix-wide approach would be better.

Comment: I don't care about such corner cases.

Answer (score 3):

What about this oneliner?

```bsh
for f in *.txt; do echo -e "\n==> $f <=="; head -n 20 "$f" | tail -n 6; done
```

When run in the currect directory, it loops over all the `.txt` files using the `*.txt` glob and then for each file prints a header and does the head, tail thing.

Comment: Actually, I am already using this option and hoping that there might be a better way to define head-tail piping as a single function. I should have excluded `for do` option in my OP.

Comment: No problem, but yes you could have mentioned that :-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that while [standard `head`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) can take more than one filename as argument and outputs those `==> filename <==` headers, [standard `tail`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) can only take one filename as argument (the behaviour is unspecified if you pass more than one.

Here instead of using a shell loop, you could use `gawk`:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{print sep"==> "substr(FILENAME, 3)" <=="; sep = "\n"}
      FNR >= 15
      FNR == 20 {nextfile}' ./*.txt
```

You could make it a function:

```
linerange() (
  min=$1 max=$2
  shift 2
  exec gawk -v min="$min" -v max="$max" -e '
    BEGINFILE{print sep"==> "FILENAME" <=="; sep = "\n"}
    FNR > max {nextfile}
    FNR >= min' -E /dev/null "$@"
)
```

And then:

```
linerange 15 20 *.txt
```

`gawk`, like any `awk` has that problem that an argument in the form of `var=value` is taken as a variable assignment instead of an input filename. That means that if some of your `.txt` files are for instance `foo=bar.txt` that won't work properly (you can have more annoying side effects for things like `ARGC=0.txt` or `ORS=.txt`...).

We work around that in the first case by using a `./` prefix (which we strip later with `substr(FILENAME, 3)` and `-E` in the second case (passing it an empty file: /dev/null, but using the fact that  assignment arguments are not processed when `-E` is used).